# Add text in the wordepress login form header

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, hook

I am trying to add text in the login form above username. i tried some code in fuctions.php file but nothing is showing in the frontend of wp-login page.

this the function i have created.

```
function filter_login_form_top_text( $var ) { 
// make filter magic happen here... 
$var = "Login to view the manual - into login form";
return $var; }; add_filter( 'login_form_top', 'filter_login_form_top_text', 10, 2 );
```

we are using default wordpress login from

i am following [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) link to make changes

can anyone please help me to make this changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function emqube_change_text_on_login_form($text){
   if(in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php'))){
     if ($text == 'Username'){$text = 'text_you_want Username';} // for login form
       if ($text == 'Username or Email:'){$text = 'text_you_want Username or Email:';} // for forgot password
        }
            return $text;
     } add_filter( 'gettext', 'emqube_change_text_on_login_form' );
```

i added to replace the label text with the text i required...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file to add text above the login form:

```
function my_custom_login_message() {
    return "A custom login message";
}

add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

Comment: i have done that but its coming below the logo i want that text above the username label.